# Google Sheets: How do I include a newline within a field in a local .tsv file I want to import

Tags: google-sheets

I know that **in Google Sheets** I can type Control-Return to create a sort of "phantom" return that starts a new line **within a field.** But what is the actual character that represents this? Obviously it's not ASCII code 13, as that is the record separator.

I would like to be able to include this mystery character **in a local .tsv file** which I import into Google sheets, so that these multi-line fields will display as such. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it's CHAR(34)

so something like the following in a cell would give two distinct lines of text...

```
="direct text input"&A3&" more text"&CHAR(34)&"Newline with new text"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. CHAR(34) just inserts a double-quote (") into the text. I double-checked, and that is indeed the ASCII code for ".

Comment: Okay, I tried it with CHAR(10), and that works in a formula, but Sheets treats that character as a record separator if I include the actual character in the file I'm trying to import (as opposed to expressing as a function, which would be impractical to do in the raw text file. Not sure if what I want to do is possible...

Comment: Of course.  My bad.  Not sure why 34 popped into my head.  CHAR(10) is what i was thinking of.  I guess it might not be possible, seems like it's an issue with the uploading software though, not google sheets?

Comment: No worries! I think there must be some special encoding that takes place "under the hood" on Google Sheets to make returns within lines possible. In a plain text file, a new line is a new line is a new line. ASCII code 10 is the record separator, there's no way to have it mean anything different from that. Thanks again for your responses!

Comment: BTW, I did figure out that in Apple Numbers, the magical mystery character  is \x2028. I can grep for my own multi-line separator character in my source file and replace it with this in a Perl script that creates a new .tsv file that Apple Numbers will import and display correctly. I'm assuming that Sheets uses this or some other whitespace character, but that character can't be captured by copying the cell to the clipboard, nor by downloading the sheet and examining its contents. Either way, you just see a \r, which is ASCII code 10.

Comment: The good news for me is that Apple Numbers is a totally workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** Google Sheets: How do I include a newline within a field in a local .tsv file I want to import

**A:** Surround that field with `"`

**Update**: Only when working with CSV. Google Sheets TSV doesn't seem to include the 'new lines'. More info on the link at the end.

---

In technical drawing class I learnt that if you don't know how to get A-->C, try to go C-->A and draw conclusions to help you achieve your goal.

If you have this CSV text file

[image]

The google sheet will look like this

[image]

Which I obtained going the other way around.

If surrounding the field with `"` is not possible, you may want to use this formula, which does the opposite (changes 'new line' for § ) [adapt to your needs].

```
# For a whole column, if there are 'new lines' in the cell, 
# copy the cell changing them to '§' otherwise copy the cell 'as is'
={"description";ArrayFormula(IF( REGEXMATCH(G2:G; char(10)) ; REGEXREPLACE(G2:G;char(10);char(167));G2:G))}
```

More rambling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74291964/dealing-with-multiline-fields-in-google-sheet-when-exported-to-csv-or-tsv-and-re)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@MattKing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60570142/2755803), an import of a `*.tsv` file containing this example content (note the double-quoting within the 2nd column value) ...

```
"example value with no line breaks" "=""line one""&CHAR(10)&""line two"""
```

... seems to have the desired outcome ...

[image]