# Dealing with multiline fields in Google Sheet when exported to csv or tsv and retrieved using Python requests.get()

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets

Lets say I have a Google Sheet that looks like this.

[image]

You can export it so it can be reached with a URL similar to this

```
# CSV
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/Eis4Ya-Le9Py/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv
# TSV
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/Eis4Ya-Le9Py/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=tsv
```

If you download the file and open it on Open Office, you can clearly see that it recognize the multilines.

[image]

And that is because the field with multiple lines get enclosed in "".

In a plain text editor it looks like

[image]

However, and here is the problem, if I get the file using python requests library, the double quotes are removed.

```
import requests

r=requests.get(url)

print(r.text)
print(r.content)
print(r.headers)


id  description
1   one line
2   line1 line2
3   l1 l2 empty line below  end
4   normal

b'id\tdescription\r\n1\tone line\r\n2\tline1 line2\r\n3\tl1 l2 empty line below  end\r\n4\tnormal'

{'Content-Type': 'text/tab-separated-values', 'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOW-FROM https://docs.google.com', ... , 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
```

Why?

How can I change that behavior?

I know there is a library for dealing with **csv** files, but I cannot use it in the environment I am in.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the `requests` library. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569221/google-sheets-how-do-i-include-a-newline-within-a-field-in-a-local-tsv-file-i) that I think is related to your question. I tested downloading both `.csv` and `.tsv`, opened it in a text editor and multiline only shows in the `.csv` file. If you run your Python code with the `.csv` export URL do you experience the same behaviour or it only happens with `.tsv`?

Comment: You are right. Behavior is different in tsv / csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Lorena Gomez I found the answer.

The behavior is different whether you request a tsv / csv file *because* tsv files do not include the 'newline(s)' that may occur within the fields.

In code:

```
url_base="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PA...be/pub?gid=0&single=true&output="

import io
import requests

# simple test
# file exported as csv
url=url_base+"csv"

s=requests.get(url)
print("-------- CSV -----------")
print(s.text)
print(s.content)

url=url_base+"tsv"

s=requests.get(url)
print("-------- TSV -----------")
print(s.text)
print(s.content)
```

Produces

```
-------- CSV -----------
,
1,one line
2,"two
lines"
3,"three

lines"
4,"empty below

end"
b',\r\n1,one line\r\n2,"two\nlines"\r\n3,"three\n\nlines"\r\n4,"empty below\n\nend"'
-------- TSV -----------
    
1   one line
2   two lines
3   three  lines
4   empty below  end
b'\t\r\n1\tone line\r\n2\ttwo lines\r\n3\tthree  lines\r\n4\tempty below  end'
```

Opening the 2 in a text editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@Rub's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4752223/rub) answer, the issue is not the `requests` library. Based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) information:

> A tab-separated values (TSV) file is a simple text format for storing data in a tabular structure... Each record in the table is one line of the text file. Each field value of a record is separated from the next by a tab character.

So that means it is expected that line breaks will not be preserved once you export to a `.tsv` file.